# Maintaing bonuses when stage is complete

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am working on a simple game you start off with three "special skills" . When you click the button you have two left etc etc till you have none. However when I go too a new stage I am back with 3. That is wrong, I want to keep the same amount of "skillls" that I had from stage 1.

I know this was happening because of the code below. I am initializing my "powers" in the initWithSize and this is called everytime my stage is loaded.

```
 -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size level:(int)level {
  if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    power1=33;
    power2=3;
    power3=3;

    NSDictionary *config=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:
                           @"Levels" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

I editted my code to look like this.
So if it is stage 0 my powers are initialized as I state and when I move too stage 1 it is continued.
However when I move over to stage one my powers are  blank/zero as im not exactly sure what should be my if condition if i am NOT in stage zero/blank

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size level:(int)level {
  if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

 //   power1=33;
//    power2=3;
//   power3=3;

    NSDictionary *config=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:
                           @"Levels" ofType:@"plist"]];

    if (level==0) {
      power1=33;
      power2=3;
      power3=3;

    }

    _level=level;
```

Game won

```
 GameLevelScene *newScene = [[GameLevelScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size
                                            level:_level+1];
```

Comment: The higher level code (that calls `initWithSize`) needs to keep track of which skills are available.

Comment: @user3386109 i added where I call my next stage. must i add the "skills" too initwithsize?

Comment: I mean, pass them in as parameters the same way i pass in the level

Comment: You can add the skills as parameters to `initWithSize`, but you'll also need a mechanism to update the skills when they are used on a level.  So a better solution might be to define a protocol that allows  the GameLevelScene to query and update the skills as needed.

Comment: @user3386109 Well i have a method in the ttouches began so when i touch the power button it minuses one from the "amount of powers" i have. when i get too zero it cantt be used. will that suffice  or i need more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. I do not know your full code so I think using `NSUserDefaults` would probably be the safest bet in your case.

At the end of a level, just before moving on to the next level, write your players attributes to `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
NSString *valueToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",someIntValue];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"Power1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Then at the beginning at the next level you can read back the saved values like this:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Power1"];
if(!savedValue)
{
    NSLog(@"no value saved");
} else {
    long someIntValue = [savedValue integerValue];
}
```

If you are somewhat unfamiliar with NSUserDefaults, you should read the [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Works perfectly and again thanks for your help. However can you suggest a better place to initialize my powers. It maintains my powers from the first stages down too the others but when I go to stage 0 ( or Stage 1) I am back up to 34. I dont want my Player to gain fully power when ever they play stage 0 but i need stage 0 too set the power in case they never playe before

Comment: @Jennifer - The best places to setup your player's attributes would either be in the init method or another method which gets called from the init method. It really does not matter where you do it or when, as long as it happens before the actual game play starts. If you save and read from NSUserDefaults, the values will always be what you expect them to be.

Comment: Works better than expected. even keeps the value when i quit the game.